# OS X Homebrew needs to create build directory for cmake

Tags: ruby, macos, cmake, homebrew

I have a simple homebrew script which I'm trying to build the library cmake-basis with. However, it cannot be built in-source with cmake, and I need to create a separate build directory. Typically in bash I would do the following:

```
git clone https://github.com/schuhschuh/cmake-basis.git -b develop ~/cmake-basis 
cd ~/cmake-basis && mkdir build && cd build 
cmake .. -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local 
make 
make install
```

I'm trying to make a homebrew script to automate this:

```
# Documentation: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/blob/master/share/doc/homebrew/Formula-Cookbook.md
#                /usr/local/Library/Contributions/example-formula.rb
# PLEASE REMOVE ALL GENERATED COMMENTS BEFORE SUBMITTING YOUR PULL REQUEST!

class CmakeBasis < Formula
  desc "cmake build and installer generation tools"
  homepage "https://github.com/schuhschuh/cmake-basis"
  url "https://github.com/schuhschuh/cmake-basis.git", :using => :git, :tag => "v3.1.0"
  version "3.1"
  #sha256 ""

  depends_on "cmake" => :build
  depends_on "doxygen" => :recommended
  depends_on :python => :required
  # todo: add sphinx python dependency
  #depends_on :x11 # if your formula requires any X11/XQuartz components

  # The optional devel block is only executed if the user passes `--devel`.
  # Use this to specify a not-yet-released version of a software.
  devel do

    url "https://github.com/schuhschuh/cmake-basis.git", :using => :git, :branch => "develop"

  end

  head do

    url "https://github.com/schuhschuh/cmake-basis.git", :using => :git, :branch => "master"

  end

  def install
    args = %W[
    ]
    # ENV.deparallelize  # if your formula fails when building in parallel
    system "cmake", "-G", "Unix Makefiles", buildpath, *(std_cmake_args + args)
    system "make"
    system "make", "install"
  end



  test do
    # `test do` will create, run in and delete a temporary directory.
    #
    # This test will fail and we won't accept that! It's enough to just replace
    # "false" with the main program this formula installs, but it'd be nice if you
    # were more thorough. Run the test with `brew test cmake-basis`. Options passed
    # to `brew install` such as `--HEAD` also need to be provided to `brew test`.
    #
    # The installed folder is not in the path, so use the entire path to any
    # executables being tested: `system "#{bin}/program", "do", "something"`.
    system "false"
  end
end
```

However, it reports the following error:

```
CMake Error at src/cmake/ProjectTools.cmake:666 (message):
  This project should not be configured & build in the source directory:

    /tmp/cmake-basis20150811-955-1b0sqck

  You must run CMake in a separate build directory.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  src/cmake/ProjectTools.cmake:1952 (basis_buildtree_asserts)
  src/cmake/ProjectTools.cmake:2156 (basis_project_begin)
  CMakeLists.txt:66 (basis_project_impl)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
```

How do I use homebrew to perform the equivalent of the `cd ~/cmake-basis && mkdir build && cd build` so it will create a separate directory for me to run cmake in?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks to [DomT4](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/issues/42834#issuecomment-130120893) at homebrew for the solution:

```
def install
  mkdir "build" do
    system "cmake", "-G", "Unix Makefiles", "..", *std_cmake_args
    system "make"
    system "make", "install"
 end
end
```